# Calculating the integral using residues.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

[image]

How can this integral be calculated using Cauchy's basic residue theorem? I tried to represent $cos(\alpha x)$ as $Re[e^{i\alpha x}]$, and try to calculate the general integral in this form:

$\int\limits_0^\infty Re[\frac{e^{i\alpha x}}{ch(x)+ch(a)}]dx$

However, due to the fact that $\alpha$ is a complex number, such reasoning will not be correct.

Comment: Is $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha) \neq 0$? If so then, supposing it is positive, you can treat the integral with $e^{i\alpha x}$ with a contour in the upper half plane and the integral with $e^{-i\alpha x}$ with a contour in the lower half plane. Or reverse the roles if the real part is negative.

Comment: Well, generally speaking, $Re(\alpha)$ can be anything in this problem.

Comment: If it is zero then you have to be more careful because you don't get any "bonus decay" out of the numerator and instead have to rely entirely on the denominator. That said if this real part is zero then I think you can just recast the numerator as $\cosh(\alpha x/i)$ and treat that case separately.

Comment: what does that "ch" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate way to evaluate this integral is to use the rectangular contour: $-R\to R\to R+2\pi i\to -R+2\pi i\to -R$.

We split integral in to to part:
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos bx}{\cosh x+\cosh a}dx=\frac{1}{4}\Big(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ibx}}{\cosh x+\cosh a}dx+\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-ibx}}{\cosh x+\cosh a}dx\Big)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\big(I_0(b)+I_0(-b)\big)$$
We suppose that $\,b\in C\,$ and $\,\Im\, b\in(-1;1)$. To evaluate $I_0(b)$ we use the following contour:
[image]

It can be shown that integrals $[1]$ and $[2] \,\to 0$ at $R\to\infty$.
$$\oint\frac{e^{ibz}}{\cosh z+\cosh a}dz=I_0-I_0e^{ib(2\pi i)}=2\pi i \sum\operatorname {Res}\frac{e^{ibz}}{\cosh z+\cosh a}$$
We have two simple poles inside the contour at $z=\pi i+a$ and $z=\pi i-a$. The residues evaluation is straightforward.
$$I_0(b)\big(1-e^{ib(2\pi i)}\big)=2\pi i\Big(-\frac{e^{-\pi b+iab}}{\sinh a}+\frac{e^{-\pi b-iab}}{\sinh a}\Big)$$
$$I_0(b)=2\pi\frac{\sin (ab)}{\sinh a\sinh (\pi b)}=I_0(-b)$$
Therefore,
$$I=\frac{\pi\,\sin (ab)}{\sinh a\sinh (\pi b)}$$
Quick check: $\displaystyle I(a=b=0)=1$.

On the other hand,
$$\ \int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\cosh x+1}=2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^x\,dx}{e^{2x}+2e^x+1}=2\int_1^\infty\frac{dt}{(1+t)^2}=1$$

Comment: My compliments!

Comment: @Ron Gordon , Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! You are the best!

Comment: How did you get that there are no other  poles  other than the ones you wrote? (By the way, there poles are just $ \pi i \pm a$)

Comment: @Mr. Nobody, yes, thank you for caching the typo - correcting. Regarding the poles: $\cosh z$ should be real; it means $z=c_1+0i; c_2+\pi i; c_3+2\pi i$, where $c$ are real. These are all options for $z$ inside our rectangular contour.

Comment: @Svyatoslav, ok, thank you very much!